2 Different UI after login, should I publish as separate apps in Google Play?
I'm developing an app for my company and I'm in the process of publishing it to the Google Play Store. The app has two different layouts: one for vendors and another for users. After logging in, the app navigates to the vendor UI if the account is a vendor account, and to the employee UI for employee accounts.
My app was rejected by Google due to having two different UIs, which caused confusion and was flagged as misleading. The app listing screenshots included the employee UI with mix of vendor UI, but the Google review team still mentioned that the app was misleading when login to vendor account, then it got rejected.
Given that Apple Store feedback is faster compared to the 3-7 days for Google Play, this is becoming a significant delay. I read about other posts about using different package names to publish, which might help get through the Google review process.
Questions:

Should I split the app into two separate apps with different package
names, each showing only one UI, to pass the Google review process
more easily?
If I keep the app as is, what are the best practices for navigating the review process to avoid these misleading violations? ( I got rejected twice already)


Create Two Separate Apps

Create one app for vendors and another for employees with different
names and packages (e.g., VendorApp and EmployeeApp). Clearly describe
each app in the Play Store with separate screenshots showing only the
relevant UI.

If You Want to Keep a Single App

In the Play Store description, explain that the app has two different
UIs (one for vendors, one for employees) and how it works. Include a
step-by-step guide inside the app to explain the two UIs when users
first open it, and show screenshots for each UI separately in the Play
Store listing, labeled clearly

.
